# Query for Google Analaytics pixel with JavaScript

Tags: for-loop, google-analytics, pixel

When Google Analytics Js is added to a page, it generates a gif pixel looking like:

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmwv=9.9.9&utms=9&utmn=1234567890&utmhn=google.com&utmcs=UTF-8&utmsr=320X480&utmvp=320X480&utmsc=9000bits&utmul=en-us&utmje=9&utmfl=-&utmdt=Google&utmhid=1234567890&utmr=-&utmp=%2F&utmht=1234567890&utmac=UA-123456789-0&utmcc=sample&utmu=sample
```

I'm trying to write a functional test checking for the existence of this pixel on the page. BUt it appears this pixel is not added to the DOM so I've not been able to grab it with with either pure JavaScript:

```
document.querySelectorAll("img")
```

or jQuery:

```
jQuery("img")
```

I also don't find the pixel when viewing the page's HTML source (Hit keyboards combination Ctrl - U or Command - U).

Do you have some suggestions for me on how to grab it? Or a better way to check for the existence of Google Analytics on page (in terms of automatic / functional tests)?

Comment: Of course you don’t see any dynamic DOM manipulations in the source code – that’s only the _initial_ HTML code loaded from the server. And an `Image` object created via JS doesn’t have to be appended to the DOM to request the resource assigned to the `src` attribute value.

Comment: Right, so query for the gif seems to be challenging. Do you think I can do it with other techniques than JS (like CSS)? Atm, I'm running out of idea on how to do it ... :-|